# LINQ to XML query help needed

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML structure...

```
<Fields>
    <Field>
        <Company>My Company</Company>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Address2>Villa at beach</Address2>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Email2>email2@mail.com</Email2>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Mobile>333-888</Mobile>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <ContactMethod>Facebook</ContactMethod>
    </Field>
</Fields>
```

I would like to know how to get the element's name using LINQ? Something like this:

```
var fields = (from field in contact.XmlFields.Descendants("Field")
                   select new ContactXmlView {Field = ...,Value = ...});
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

```
Company: My Company
Address2: Villa at beach...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one descendant for each "Field" node :

```
var fields = (from field in contact.XmlFields.Descendants("Field")
                          select new ContactXmlView
                          {
                              Field = field.Descendants().First().Name,
                              Value = field.Descendants().First().Value
                          });
```